# linux command rename dates (YYYY.MMDD) to numbers(001,002,...,066,067) sequentially

Tags: linux, date, command, rename

I have renamed many files by using '`rename`'.

However, I find a problem with conversion dates to numbers.

The file name is 2021.0801, 2021.0802, .. etc. (Year.Month&date)

I need to change Month&date parts to numbers of 001, 002, etc.

So I need to rename

```
2021.0801
2021.0802
...
2021.0929
2021.0930
```

to

```
2021.001
2021.002
...
2021.0**
2021.0**
```

I saw I can do it when I use rename or #, ? but I could not see the specific way to solve this.

Could you please let me know the way to rename these?

p.s. I tried `num=001; for i in {0801..0930}; do rename $i $num *; (($num++)); done` but it showed

```
2021.001
2021.001001
2021.001001001001
...
```

Additionally, `ls 2021.*` shows only the files that I want to change.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Are there any other files `2021.*`? If the numbers represent a date you should probably make clear that `2021.0901` follows `2021.0831`. What do you mean with "I find a problem with conversion dates to numbers"? Did you try something which did not work? Then please show what you tried and the result you get. Don't you know how to start? Then state this is your question. Can we assume that your shell is `bash`? One option would be to list and sort the file names, process the list one-by-one and format a new file name from an incremented counter.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. The shell is bash and 0931 means Month : 09, day : 31. There are other files of dates from August 1st to September 31th.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add requested information or clarification. **[Edit] your question instead.** I don't understand tha last sentence in your comment. Are there any files that represent dates not in the range Aug 1 to Sep 30? Or in other words: Does `ls 2021.*` list only the files you want to rename or also other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script contains a few errors. I suggest to use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your scripts.

After fixing the errors, the (unfinished) result is

```
#!/bin/bash
num=001; for i in {0801..0930}; do rename "$i" "$num" ./*; ((num++)); done
```

This has 3 remaining problems.

1. The range `{0801..0930}` includes the numbers `0831`, `0832`, ... `0899`, `0900`. This can be fixed by using two ranges `{0801..0831} {0901..0930}`
2. The increment operation `((num++))` does not preserve the leading zeros. This can be fixed by conditionally adding 1 or 2 zeros.
3. You call `rename` for every combination which will check all files and probably rename only one. As you know the exact file names you can replace this with a `mv` command.

The final version is

```
num=1; for i in {0801..0831} {0901..0930}; do
  if [[ num -lt 10 ]] ; then
    new="00$num";
  elif [[ num -lt 100 ]] ; then
    new="0$num";
  else
    new="$num"; # this case is not necessary here
  fi;
  mv "2021.$i" "2021.$new";
  ((num++));
done
```

The script handles leading zeros for values of 1, 2 or 3 digits which is not needed here as all numbers are less than 100. For this case, it can be simplified as

```
num=1; for i in {0801..0831} {0901..0930}; do
  if [[ num -lt 10 ]] ; then
    new="00$num";
  else
    new="0$num";
  fi;
  mv "2021.$i" "2021.$new";
  ((num++));
done
```

The script will execute these commands:

```
mv 2021.0801 2021.001
mv 2021.0802 2021.002
...
mv 2021.0830 2021.030
mv 2021.0831 2021.031
mv 2021.0901 2021.032
mv 2021.0902 2021.033
...
mv 2021.0929 2021.060
mv 2021.0930 2021.061
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop. This single command will do it all :

```
rename -n 'BEGIN{our $num=1}{our $num;s/\d+$/sprintf("%03d", $num)/e; $num += 1}' 2021.*
```

Remove `-n` once the resulting renaming looks good.

Comment: There are two versions of the rename tool. The code in the question uses the syntax of this (util-linux?) version: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html while your solution uses this https://manpages.debian.org/buster/rename/prename.1p.en.html.

Comment: @Bodo, thanks, you are right, I'm not aware of the first version.